# liquid template - using the replace filter to print out </em><em>

Tags: liquid

trying to figure out why:

```
{{ page.excerpt | prepend:'<em>' | append:'</em>' | replace: ',' ,'</em> <em>' }}
```

turns this:

```
hashtag.1, hashtag.2, hashtag.3
```

into this:

```
<em>#LetsMove <em> #newark <em> #JJLA2012</em>
```

..

```
somehow the </em> is not passing through.
```

the html tags seem to close themselves, sort of non-uniformly, so we keep ending up
w/a mess of weird half-over-nested markup.

Comment: Please post the exact declaration of excerpt and the surrounding markup where you are displaying it. Your code works for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your hashtags are an array, not a string.

The replace is never happening, instead are prepending to each hashitem.

Troubleshoot by using this:

```
{{ page.excerpt | replace: ',','foobar' }}
```

And see if foobar prints out at all. Are you sure your hashitems in page.excerpt?

Output filters go left to right, so in your example: prepend, append, replace. Or in this example

```
{{ output | filterA | filterB | filterC }}
```

the order would be

1. filterA
2. filterB
3. filterC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ page.excerpt | array_to_sentence_string | prepend:'<em>' | append:'</em>' | replace: ',' ,'</em> <em>' }}
```